# How can I used ensamble balancing result in base algorithms

Tags: python-3.x

I have large imbalance data set and I will apply under sampling + boosting ,sampling + bagging 
to balance my data . 
my question how apply base algorithms such as Knn on result of balancing 
ex:

```
rusboost = RUSBoostClassifier(random_state=0)  
rusboost.fit(X_train, y_train)
RUSBoostClassifier(...)
y_pred = rusboost.predict(X_test)
```

how take the result from this code as label and feature and inter it in another training

```
balanced_accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```